# what is the different between scalar difference equations and difference equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the different between scalar difference equations and difference equations? What the scalar here means?

Comment: Quick gogling seems to suggest that a scalar equation is one where the unknown sequence is a sequence of numbers, as opposed to a sequence of vectors.

Comment: yes, I know your say but I want to find new definition.

Comment: Is the scalar mean one dimension?  How to tell which is one-dimensional equation?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if we talk about a scalar difference equation/scalar differential equation, it implies that we only have **one** function that we are trying to find.

Example $a(n+2)=a(n+1)+a(n)$ or $y'(t)=y(t)$.

A (system) of difference equations or differential equations consists of **at least two equations** (which should not be linearly independent) and in most cases the number of equations is equal to the number of unknown functions.

Example $a_1(n+2)=a_1(n+1)+a_2(n+1)+a_1(n)$ and $a_2(n+2)=2a_2(n+2)$ or $y_1'(t)=y_1(t)+2y_2(t)$
$y_2'(t)=y_1(t)y_2(t)$.